# SQL - trigger stops inserting data

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

I created trigger which is below and checks if inserting data is correct. 
And I generate some test data and want to insert it. When first "insert" is incorrect it stops inserting other test data.

Is it possible to do that, when it finds incorrect data it skips that and goes to the next "insert"?

I use MS SQL Server.

```
create trigger ReservedPlacesLimited on ConferenceParticipants
After insert, update as
begin
    if exists(select cp.ConfReservID, cr.places
        from ConferenceParticipants as cp
        inner join ConferenceReservation as cr on cp.ConfReservID=cr.ConfReservID
        group by cp.ConfReservID, cr.places having cr.Places<COUNT(cp.confPartID) )
    begin
        RAISERROR('Error: Too much participants from this reservation', 16,1);
        Rollback Transaction;
    end
end
go
```

Comment: You need an `Instead of Trigger`, join the `Inserted` table with `ConferenceParticipants` and only insert the rows which are valid.

Comment: A trigger that makes no use of 'inserted' or 'deleted' is unlikely to be a very useful or very performant trigger.

Comment: To be more clear, your trigger isn't looking at what's being inserted or updated... it's just looking at the existing tables. Once you insert data that satisfies the IF statement, it will ALWAYS be satisfied, until you delete the rows that satisfy it.  Side note: the error message should say "too many" not "too much", just FYI.

Comment: Another part of your problem is that you are inserting multiple record but want it to continue with the good records. Triggers do not run row by row nor should they for performance reasons. I think in part, your business rules are not clear (or at least they are not to me) which might be part of why you are having trouble getting a correct result.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you need to be aware that there are two pseudo-tables called Inserted and Deleted that are available in a trigger. For an insert, you will want to reference the inserted table which contains teh exact record being processed for insert. Updates would reference both Inserted (new values) and Deleted (old values) and triggers on Delete would reference the Deleted table.

Another thing you need to understand is that the trigger operates on a group of records not one at a time. Even if your application only submits one record at a time, then you still need to test the results when multiple records are sent because sooner or later someone will do such an insert from the query window for a special case.

So if you want to fail some of a group, but not all of them, then the logic is going to be far more complicated. In your case I would set a variable with the current datetime and one with the current user (or create a batch number). Then I would have the trigger select only records that would pass the check and insert them into the table. I would  then select the ones that would have failed and insert them and the datetime and user variables into an exception table, then pass the error message out but include the name of the exception table, so they can find the bad records. Then I might add a screen to your application so they can see the rejected records. This is a complex process and tricky to get correct and users are likely to misinterpret what happened.

However, I personally would prefer to reject the whole insert because the users might want to then pick and choose who should be eliminated from the list rather than just failing the last ones in the process or the ones ordered by last name or whatever business rule you use in the trigger.

Ultimately this is a problem in the business rules. First you need to know exactly which records should be rejected if there are too many or you need to reject all of them and have them resubmit. Personally I would let them know how many they should have in the error message. Something like:

> There were 20 participants submitted, but only 10 available places. 
>   Please resubmit after adjusting the data.

Of course the numbers could be populated by variables as p[art of the trigger